# FCM Data Message should be non-collapsibl by default

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Based on the documentation, it is my understanding that there are two types of messages that Firebase can send: Notification and Data. Also, they can be either collapsible or non-collapsible with non-collapsible being the default for data messages. This would mean that each message is delivered to the client app. See below:

[image: Documentation]

However, when I send data messages to my client they are collapsed. For example, I send one and it appears in the notification bar with no problem but if I don't open it and another message comes in, it is replaced by the new message. Here's some of my code.

Data message:

```
    //create the notification payload
            let payload = {
                data: {
                  title: 'Title',
                  context: context,
                  parent: parent,
                  body: user + " commented on your contribution.",
                  sound: 'default'
                }
              };
            //send the notification
            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(userToken, payload).then(ok =>{
              console.log('Notification sent to: ' + submitter);
            }).catch(error => {
              console.log('Could not send notification.');
            });
```

What am I doing wrong? I want each notification to appear and not be replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are debugging at the wrong end. The actual problem is on the client side where you are posting the notification.
While posting the notification if the notification id is the same Android OS will replace the existing notification. 
Look for the notify() in your code. Refer to this doc for more details : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify(int, android.app.Notification)

Comment: You're right. I had completely overlooked this. I'm now generating a random id for each notification that comes in. Thanks.